# How to get perspective for app portfolio image

Tags: gimp, perspective, portfolio

I got a free template for app portfolio. It looks like this

[image]

So I insert a screenshot (this is just a sample) and rotate it -45 degrees.

[image]

[image]

but it is nowhere right as it should be.

First I am not sure if this is really 45 degrees angle. And even worse, I have no idea how to push the image into perspective to it fits the template.

In the template, it only says "insert image here" and has no instruction on how to make it perfectly fit.

I am using Gimp. Would it be easier or better to do in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Comment: Those templates usually provide a way to insert your image perfectly. Photoshop and Illustrator have Effect>3D>Rotate which can turn and twist your image into alignment.

Comment: Without seeing the layer structure I would say Photoshop would be best. What is the file type of the file you are working with?

Comment: I agree, usually there is a fastest way to obtain a mockup starting from a template. By the way, have you tried to use the [shear](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-tool-shear.html) or the [perspective](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-perspective.html) tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `File>Open` the phone image
- `File>Open as layers` the screen image
- Make sure the screen layer is active (it normally should)
- Reduce its opacity (opacity slider at top of layers list)
- Start the Perspective tool [image]
- Click the image, you should get 4 handles on the corner of the screen layer
- Drag these handles to where these corners should be on the phone image
- Click the `Transform` button in the dialog
- Set opacity back to 100%

[image]